# Erlang tail recursion

Tags: recursion, erlang, tail-recursion, erlang-shell

I've just started learning erlang and Tail recursion is killing me slowly; I can't get my head around it. I'm trying to make a program that doubles every other number in a list and I'm trying to do this with tail recursion.

Here's my code so far

```
    stripAndDoubleOdds([H|T]) -> stripAndDoubleOdds([H|T],1,[H|T]).

    stripAndDoubleOdds(F, _, []) -> F;

    stripAndDoubleOdds(_,Index,[H1|T1]) ->

    F = [] ++ 2*lists:nth(Index, [H1|T1]),  

stripAndDoubleOdds(F, Index +2, T1).
```

When I give it a list of numbers I get no output at all but if I give it a single number it can double it without a problem.

Index is meant to keep the position of the current element and it's incremented by 2 so that I get every other integer and double it. My current solution involves extracting the head, doubling it, adding it to a list then passing the tail through the process over and over again until I get an empty list and at this point I'm supposed to get my list, F back. e.g. if I enter [1,2,3,4,5] I just want it to give me a list with
[2,6,,10].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first  body recursive (it is no longer so slow):

```
stripAndDoubleOdds([H, _|T]) -> [2*H | stripAndDoubleOdds(T)];
stripAndDoubleOdds([H]) -> [2*H];
stripAndDoubleOdds([]) -> [].
```

Now tail recursive

```
stripAndDoubleOdds(L) -> lists:reverse(stripAndDoubleOdds(T, [])).

stripAndDoubleOdds([H, _|T], Acc) -> stripAndDoubleOdds(T, [2*H|Acc]);
stripAndDoubleOdds([H], Acc) -> [2*H|Acc];
stripAndDoubleOdds([], Acc) -> Acc.
```

You can also make list comprehension version which is not very efficient neither nice

```
stripAndDoubleOdds(L) ->
    [ 2*X || {X, I} <- lists:zip(L, lists:seq(1,length(L))), I rem 2 =:= 1 ].
```

Comment: Thank you, that does make my life better; I've tracked it down using paper so it's clearer now.

Comment: The function does not work with input list which have an odd length, the last term is missing.

Answer (score 1):

To build a tail recursive function that work on a list, the pattern is always the same: call a function that have an accumulator parameter in addition to the  initial list. Depending on the function to execute, the accumulator may be an integer, an empty list or any initial value needed for your algorithm.

For your example, you want to create a list from the initial one. The accumulator will be an empty list that you will fill during the successive call.

As for any recursice algorithm, you need to define the end case, that will stop the recursion and allow to return the result, in your case, it is when the initial list is emptied.

I propose you this solution which is simpler to read (IMO)

```
strd(L) -> strd(L,1,[]). % as you did, I use an integer to detect the odd indices

strd([],_,Acc) -> lists:reverse(Acc); 
%    if the order is important, you should reverse the resulr at the end rather than keeping the right order during
%    the evaluation using the ++ operator. The ++ operator force a copy of the whole list while the construction with
%    [A|B] does not need to copy B.
strd([_|Q],0,Acc) -> strd(Q,1,Acc);
strd([H|Q],1,Acc) -> strd(Q,0,[2*H|Acc]). 
%    I simply toggle the integer betwwen 1 and 0 to select the right operation using pattern matching
```

Hynek example can will work for any length af list adding a second end case:

```
stripAndDoubleOdds(L) -> stripAndDoubleOdds(L, []).

stripAndDoubleOdds([H, _|T], Acc) -> stripAndDoubleOdds(T, [2*H|Acc]);
stripAndDoubleOdds([H], Acc) -> lists:reverse([2*H|Acc]);
stripAndDoubleOdds(_, Acc) -> lists:reverse(Acc).
```

Comment: I like you explanation regarding recursion and the patterns associated with it. Thank you